# @SpringBootTest classes run in same thread although configured concurrently

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, junit5, maven-failsafe-plugin

I have several test classes that are annotated with `@SpringBootTest` and also `AutoConfigureMockMvc`.

They look like this:

```
@SpringBootTest
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
class ThymeleafFormatIT {
    @Autowired
    lateinit var mvc: MockMvc

    @Test
    fun `test something` {}
}
```

Since there are several of these tests, currently five, I want to run the test classes in parallel. I want to take the time it takes to run these tests down as far as possible.

Since I use Junit 5 and Maven, I have configured my failsafe plugin like this:

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.22.0</version>
    <executions>
        [...]
    </executions>
    <configuration>
        <properties>
            <configurationParameters>
                junit.jupiter.execution.parallel.enabled = true
                junit.jupiter.execution.parallel.mode.default = same_thread
                junit.jupiter.execution.parallel.mode.classes.default = concurrent
            </configurationParameters>
        </properties>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

If I run now `mvn integration-test` I see that multiple Spring containers get booted up, but they boot sequentially. Also, the test execution duration does not change significantly: before adding the configuration, duration was ~20 seconds, after adding it's ~19.9 seconds.

Is there something I am missing? Does the `@SpringBootTest` annotation force sequential execution, maybe by blocking a port or something? Does the failsafe plugin not pick up the configuration items? Are Junit 5 and failsage incompatible with each other?